# How to implement a stopwatch in Lua?

Tags: lua, stopwatch

How would you make a stopwatch in Lua?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Codea at all I'm afraid and you will most likely find that there are functions provided by that library for `gettime` and `sleep`. However as a pure Lua option (with the proviso that you use luasocket) the following code implements an example that could be built on.

```
socket = require('socket')


-- Define the stop watch
local start_time

function start()
    -- Start the stop watch
    start_time = socket.gettime() - 3800
end

function seconds_ellapsed()
    -- Return the number of seconds since the stop watch was started
    return socket.gettime() - start_time
end


-- As an example run the stop watch indefinately
start()

while true do

    -- Get the time ellapsed and convert it to hours, minutes and seconds
    ellapsed = seconds_ellapsed()
    hours = math.floor(ellapsed / 3600)
    minutes = math.floor((ellapsed - (hours * 3600)) / 60)
    seconds = math.floor((ellapsed - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)))

    -- Print the time ellapsed to the command line
    print(hours .. 'h', minutes .. 'm', seconds .. 's')

    -- Wait a second between each update
    socket.sleep(1)

end
```

You could look to use `os.clock` also but Lua has no builtin mechanism for setting the thread to sleep for a period (which was required for my example so I choose to use luasocket). There is a useful article on possible approaches for implementing sleep in lua here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic stopwatch, it starts/resets when the user taps the screen. This example shows elapsed minutes and seconds. If you want to count milliseconds, you can use `ElapsedTime` instead of `os.time()` and compute the number of hours, minutes etc. yourself instead of `os.date()`. Also, I don't have my iPad so there may be a bug.

```
function setup()
   fontSize(20)
   background(100, 120, 160)
   fill(255)
   toggle_timer()
end

function toggle_timer()
  timer_on = not timer_on
  if timer_on then
    start = os.time()
  end
end

function draw()
   if timer_on then
      text(os.date("%M:%S", os.difftime(os.time(), start)),
        WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
   end
end

function touched(touch)
   if touch.state == BEGAN then
      toggle_timer()
   end
end
```